# Creating a script that auto clicks a button on the site instantly (internally not manually) once the page loads in using Tampermonkey

Tags: tampermonkey

I am looking to create a script which automatically clicks a button on the site once it has loaded but I'm not exactly sure how to do it as I am a beginner any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Share your code and issue you are facing

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm unsure why but the code didn't show up in my original post, here's what I'm working from. <div class="_1GLqQ73RIbK-GyeIj1aW6V button-acceptGroupGameInvite"><style>

Comment: @Vindhyachal Kumar Please also note, the code is a lot longer after but I am unable to paste it here, later it's just color gradients and all, if there's somewhere where I could paste it for you I would, thank you so much for the help as I have just started programming. :)